# if clause produces null in json structure

Tags: json, sesam

I have a nested json-structure where I have an if-clause. The if-clause do not have a else alternative, but still it produces a null in the result. I need to remove this null, but I am unable to reference it. How can I avoid this null from appearing?

Code:

```
["list", "ObjectConnections",
    ["list",
        ["if",
            ["is-not-empty", "_S.ObjectKey-Invoice"],
            ["dict", "ObjectType", "_S.ObjectType-Invoice", "ObjectKey", "_S.ObjectKey-Invoice"]
        ],
        ["if",
            ["is-not-empty", "_S.ObjectKey-Customer"],
            ["dict", "ObjectType", "_S.ObjectType-Customer", "ObjectKey", "_S.ObjectKey-Customer"]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Result:

```
“ObjectConnections”: [
    null,
    {
    “ObjectKey”: “123456789”,
    “ObjectType”: “CustomerInfo”
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know sesam, but my guess is that the if statement ALWAYS returns a value (either the result of the sub clause if the test is true and null if false, if there is no else clause).

You probably have to use a filter of some sort to transform the resulting list and get rid of the nulls